# Facebook Lead ads third party CRM integration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a lead ad in facebook for one of my clients, I want the leads to send to his CRM as well.
The only way I found to do it (in real time) is via Facebook [webhooks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/quickstart/webhooks-integration).
I've walked through this video [tutorial](https://www.facebook.com/marketingdevelopers/videos/883648801749520/) (using javascript sdk and php webhook) but Facebook ask me to provide a "screencast" video to get access to `manage_pages` scope.
The app should only forward the leads to the CRM by the weehook, that's it.
what video should I provide? I have nothing to show in it.

Any answer will help, Thanks a lot everyone :)